# Regex that match strings in between underscores, asterisks & tilde

Tags: javascript, regex

The closes I got is this `_(.*?)_`

What regex should I use to get every instance of string in between underscores but should not be a substring of a string (check test3) and should not also get those in new line (check test4)

```
var string = "_test1 test2_ test_3_ _\n test4_ _test5_"
```

The regex should only get `_test1 test2_` & `_test5_`

Note: any character/string the word test doesn't matter

Comment: I don't find `_test1 test_` in your input

Comment: edited @AvinashRaj

Comment: `string.match(/_test[^_\n]+_/g)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj ahhh wait will test

Comment: @AvinashRaj it should select any character/string between underscore do not mind the test

Comment: `str.match(/_[a-z\d]+(?: [a-z\d]+)*_/g)`

Comment: Just as an alternative - [one for all](https://regex101.com/r/eQ0rR0/2) - [`\b_([^_\n]*)_\b|(?:^|\s)\*\b([^*\n]*)\b\*(?!\S)|(?:^|\s)~\b([^~\n]*)\b~(?!\S)`](https://jsfiddle.net/1e83byj4/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it seleceted `_\n te*s*t4_` which has new line

Comment: Where? See https://jsfiddle.net/1e83byj4/. Results: `[
    "test1 test2",
    "test5",
    "test1 test2",
    "test5",
    "test1 test2",
    "test5"
]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew some tests got whitespace on the first char like for example `adaw dawalak jawd  *test* dalkwjalkj T8*t*` it gave me [" *test"]

Comment: Sorry, I put it on actual test :/ @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Where is it? Until you post it, the question is just unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112480/discussion-between-unspeakable-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that each underscore pair is separated by a whitespace character (so no two underscores are next to one another), then this regex will work: `\b_([\w\s]+?)_\b`

To match any of the 3 cases you need, use this regex: `(?:\b|\s|^)[_*~]([\w\s]+?)[_*~](?:\s|$)`

Comment: This must me it let me do more test

Comment: Thanks! This is it

Comment: `\w` contains `\d`

Comment: How come this doesn't work on asterisks? `\b\*([\w\s]+?)\*\b`

Comment: @Unspeakable please be clear with question you ask..mention all the cases

Comment: @rock321987 sorry didn't know it's different, other cases are * and ~

Comment: @StevenLambert the regex `(?:\b|\s|^)[_*~]([\w\s]+?)[_*~](?:\s|$)` should get those with new line in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex

```
(?:^| )(_(?:[\w ]+?)_|([*~])(?:[\w ]+?)\2)(?= |$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN4bP0/4)**

*JS Demo*

```js
var re = /(?:^| )(_(?:[\w ]+?)_|([*~])(?:[\w ]+?)\2)(?= |$)/g;
var str = "_test1 test2_ test_3_ _\n test4_ *test5*  test*3* _asdf_ _ghjkl_ _mno_";
document.writeln("<pre>" + str.match(re) + "</br>" + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me do more test

Comment: How can I separate each characters? not 1 match sorry I wasn't clear again, so that would be 3 regex..

Comment: @Unspeakable can you explain?

Comment: A regex that match only strings in between underscores, another regex that match only strings in between asterisks and another regex that match only strings between tilde.

Comment: @Unspeakable you want three different regex?

Comment: Yes sorry! :( @rock321987 I actually thought 1 regex would work with the rest If I just change the identifier

Comment: @Unspeakable you can use `[*]([\w\s]+?)[*]` for `*`. you don't need word boundary for that

Comment: @Unspeakable reason is `\w` contains `_` (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`)

Comment: the regex for asterisk selected test*3* which shouldn't and also shouldn't select those that have new line in between. Same as the example I given on the question

Comment: it didn't able to select `ghjkl` in this string `"_asdf_ _ghjkl_ _mno_"` @rock321987

Answer (score 1):

For getting the required value from

> *test1 test2* test_3_ *\n test4* *test5*

use

```
_test[^_\n]+_
```

The below one works as well.

```
^_([^_]+?)_|_([^_]+?)_$

text.match(/^_([^_]+?)_|_([^_]+?)_$/g);
```

http://regexr.com/3df3m

Comment: it should select any character/string between underscore do not mind the test string

Comment: the regex didnt able to get the `_asdad_` in this string `adaw dawalak jawd  _asdad_ dalkwjalkj T8_t_ `

Comment: it didn't able to select `ghjkl` in this string `"_asdf_ _ghjkl_ _mno_"` @KrishnaThota